# Perl Read a file into a variable and add suffix to each lines

Tags: perl

I'm very new to Perl and I'm having a hard time find out what I want.

I have a text file containing something like

```
text 2015-02-02:
- blabla1
- blabla2
text2 2014-12-12:
- blabla
- ...
```

I'm trying to read the file, put it in var, add  to end of each line (of my var) and use it to send it to a web page.

This is what I have for the moment. It works except for the  part.

```
if (open (IN, "CHANGELOG.OLD")) { 
        local $/;   
        $oldchangelog = <IN>'</br>';            
        close (IN);
    $tmplhtml{'CHANGELOG'} = $oldchangelog;
} else {
    # changelog not available
    $tmplhtml{'CHANGELOG'} = "Changelog not available";
}
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: This looks like a YAML  file, if so you should use a YAML parser to read YAML files. [`YAML::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Tiny) is a nice one, there are several others on CPAN.

Comment: `<IN>'</br>'` is a syntax error... Perhaps you meant to do `<IN> . '</br>'` Although if you are trying to view a YAML like format on a web page, you might want to wrap it in `<pre> .. </pre>` instead.

Comment: I _think_ it's trying to have a `<BR/>` at the end of each line, which isn't going to work with file slurping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone comments - this looks like YAML, so parsing as YAML is probably more appropriate.

However to address your scenario:

- 3 argument file opens are good.
- you're using `local $/;` which means you're reading the whole file into a string. This is not suitable for line by line processing.

Looks like you're putting everything into one element of a hash. Is there any particular reason you're doing this?

Anyway:

```
if ( open ( my $input, "<", "CHANGELOG.OLD" ) ) {
    while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
        $tmplhtml{'CHANGELOG'} .= $line . " <BR/>\n";
    } 
}
else { 
    $tmplhtml{'CHANGELOG'} = "Changelog not available";
}
```

As an alternative - you can render text 'neatly' to HTML using `<PRE>` tags.

Comment: I don't know what YAML is, I'll look at it. I'm just wanted to display my changelog (.txt) in an HTML page. aniway, that was it! so simple when it's there :-) thanks !